# Servlet does't load values from JSP via request.getParameter()

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

This is very strange but maybe I missed something while study Servlets/JSP.Below you can find snippet of the code that doesn't work for me.
In JSP I have:

```
<h4 "name="update_company" id="update_company" value="'+modal_company+'" style="font-size:x-large"/>'+modal_company+'</h4>
```

and in Servlet:

```
DataBean update=new DataBean();
update.setCompanyName(request.getParameter("update_company"));
```

This doesn't work and update_company variable stores as null

However in the same div i have rest of the form that are editable(input):

```
<label for="'+modal_street+'">Address</label>
<input class="form-control" name="street" id="street" 
value="'+modal_street+'"/>

update.setStreet(request.getParameter("street"));
```

That part works just fine.

Question is.Is there some HTML tags that are restricted to use with request.getParameter().I thought that servlet is looking for name attribute and value.Doesn't matter if this is dynamic(input) or static(h4 or p). Appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code is part of html `header`

```
<h4 "name="update_company" id="update_company" value="'+modal_company+'" style="font-size:x-large"/>'+modal_company+'</h4>
```

Above value won't be passed.

You need to change this to `input`, which you did in later code.

---

**Edited:**

If you want this to be non-editable then, use `readonly` option as below.

```
<input class="form-control" name="street" id="street" 
     value="'+modal_street+'" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.I can confirm its working with <input> but I don't want to be that part of the website editable.I tested with <p> and <label> tags and outcome was the same.(not working).I was thinking that servlet reads from "value=" which is there.That part is confusing.

Comment: @pjtrowski you don't want it to be editable or visible ?

Comment: It has to be visibleI don't want this to be editable(company name).Just rest of the page is editable(company details)...That data is loaded from mySQL.After editing goes back to DB.However name of the company doesn't change, servlet requires unedited name to run UPDATE querry

Answer (score 0):

Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Look closely, In your html segment I am seeing  a double quote before `name` attribute  is that a typo? `<h4 "name="update_company"...`

Comment: Double quote is a typo...Copy and pasted one character too much.